# Docker compose and postgres official image environment variables

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psql

Actually I'm using the following docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.3'

  services:
    postgres:
      container_name: postgres
      image: postgres:latest
      restart: always
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
        POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
        PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
      volumes:
        - ./data/postgres/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
```

I use also this .env file in the same directory of the docker-compose.yml file:

```
POSTGRES_USER=dbadm
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dbpwd
POSTGRES_DB=db
```

Then I run a bash shell into container this way:

```
docker exec -ti postgres bash
```

And after this invoke the command:

```
psql -h postgres -U dbadm db
```

And I get the error:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "dbadm"
```

The strange fact is that if use the default image parameters:

```
psql -h postgres -U admin database
```

And insert the default password "password", it logs me in, and seems it's ignoring the environment variables.

What am I missing?

Additional logs from docker-compose up logs:

```
postgres    | 2017-10-15 09:19:15.502 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres    | 2017-10-15 09:19:15.502 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres    | 2017-10-15 09:19:15.505 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres    | 2017-10-15 09:19:15.524 UTC [22] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-10-15 09:02:21 UTC
postgres    | 2017-10-15 09:19:15.530 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Cannot see any "RUN" line about user, database and password setup.

Comment: It is confusing, you are trying to login as dbadm and it doesn't work but then you are saying that you can login as admin. Have you tried using the admin user in your .env file?

Comment: Thanks for the interest @Sergiu as I said it works using the default values from the image but it's not my problem.

Comment: Could you please run this env | grep POSTGR inside your postgres container?

Comment: Did you try to specify values directly (POSTGRES_USER: dbadm, etc)? Not sure, but maybe you also need to add `env_file: .env` to your config as mentioned in docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file

Comment: Another thing to try: shift `environment` section forward, to place it under `postgres` instead of having it on the `services` level.

Comment: @Sergiu I get POSTGRES_DB=db
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dbpwd
POSTGRES_USER=dbdmin

Comment: @BorisSerebrov my fault bad identation, now I have corrected the way I'm using it on my local machine, but still have the problem, also writing explicitly env file path, that its not needed when have the default name and shouldn't need to be overridden

Comment: It seems related to the volume mounting overriding the content of the pgdata directory some way if I revmove the volumes directive it goes on.

Comment: @zioMitch the exact same setup works for me, except that I am using docker compose version 2.

Comment: @BorisSerebrov strange, really seems something related to volumes mounting.

Comment: Maybe something with access permissions to the local folder then? I tried it with `- ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata` and it works both when I have `./pgdata` created initially or when I don't have it (then it is created by container). Once I shutdown / restart the container, the data is preserved.
Here is the setup that I now have - https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/tree/master/docker-postgres

Comment: Yes @BorisSerebrov data is preserved, and probably is something with permissions when mounting an external volume.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156772/discussion-between-ziomitch-and-boris-serebrov).

Comment: @BorisSerebrov yes using same but I have       - ./data/postgres/pgdata:${POSTGRES_DATA_DIR} and it doesn't work with compose 3.3

Comment: And what is `${POSTGRES_DATA_DIR}`? It is not present in your question. Does it work if you use static path (`/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata`)?

Comment: Just another var, and result it's the same, it's only a variable

Answer (score 8):

according to https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres documentation.

Warning: the Docker specific variables will only have an effect if you start the container with a data directory that is empty; any pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a docker-compose yml and .env file with the details you've provided and everything works fine as you can see from the pictures below:

[image]
[image]

I think your problem lies when you are passing the *-h*  parameter.

Inside the container will always be *localhost* however, outside you will have to pass:

```
hostname: postgres
```

inside your docker-compose file so it will have the postgres hostname

Comment: Using localhost it allows local connections and skip totally the user created. The problem is on how I'm mounting the directory for data. @sergiu

Comment: Yes that's right, you are only using local connections, however, in your /etc/hosts file you will have to add the container IP and postgres, as follows: 

0.0.0.0      postgres

and then try to connect

Comment: Fine it seems that setting the env variable PGDATA creates a volume in wich postgres stores db binaries and configuration files (also accesses). Then I mount a volume that I want to be on the host for simplicity during local development. But mounting the volume will override all it seems. Am I wrong?